# Capturing values produced during iteration and plotting them against the iteration index

Tags: list-manipulation

```
numTimes = 10;
testList = 
  ParallelTable[
    NMinimize[
      {funcVS[x1t, y1t], -0.0535 <= x1t <= -0.0424 && -0.0535 <= y1t <= -0.0284}, 
      {x1t, y1t}, 
      Method -> {"NelderMead", RandomSeed -> k}],  
    {k, numTimes}]]
```

Is it possible to capture the values of the variables and the objective function in each iteration? I want to plot them against the number of iterations.

`FuncVS` is bit complex, so I am not adding it here.

Comment: see [StepMonitor](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StepMonitor.html) and [EvaluationMonitor](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html)